# Add sheet to existing excel file with Laravel Excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I am using Laravel Excel 2.1.  I have an array of data that I want to add as a new sheet to an existing excel file and save it locally.

Here is the code I am trying

```
Excel::load(base_path() . '/storage/app/surveyFilters/' . $surveyFilter->filename, function($file) use($data) {
    $file->sheet('Individuals - Tagged', function($sheet) use($data)
    {
        $sheet->fromArray($data);
    });

})->store('xls', public_path('assets'));
```

I get this error "Call to a member function fromArray() on null".  If I var_dump $data right before the call and exit it shows my array so $data is not null.  I also tried with() instead of fromArray() but get similar error message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error message is saying `$sheet` is null, not `$data`

Comment: You are correct.  $sheet is null.  Any idea why $sheet is null?  If I comment out  $sheet->fromArray($data); it runs fine and puts adds the excel file to the path I give it so it loads the file fine.

Comment: From reading the documentation, it appears as though you're trying to add a sheet on an already created file, whereas the documentation only shows that you can do that from a newly created instance from `Excel::create()`

Comment: Thanks. That would explain it as that is what i am trying to do.